# Finding coefficient of $x^{15}$

Tags: generating-functions

$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)\cdot (x^2+x^3+x^4+…)^5$$

I have done a little :

$$x(1 + x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\cdot x^{10}(1 + x^2+x^3+…)^5$$

By generating functions:

$$\begin{align}&x^{11}\cdot\frac{1 - x^5}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x)^5}\\[1ex] 
\implies &x^{11}(1 - x^5)\cdot\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}\\[1.5ex]
\implies &x^{11}(1 - x^5) \cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5} x^n\\
\end{align}$$

How am I supposed to find $x^{15}$or any other one like $x^{18} , x^{19}$ 
Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: Now think about multiplying out the product you created.  You have an $x^[11}$ and either a $1$ or an $x^5$, what do you need from the 3rd term of the product in order to get $x^{15}$?

Comment: @sharding4 I need $x^4$ ?

Comment: Do you see any way to get an $x^4$?

Comment: Check your rules for exponents.  $x^{11} \cdot  (-x^5) $ already has exponent greater than $15$, so that you can't get an $x^{15}$ that way.  The $x^{11} \cdot 1 \cdot \binom {9}{4} x^4$ is correct.

Comment: @sharding4 Hey , thanks . I just wana clarify my understanding : Suppose I had to find coefficient of $x^{19}$ for the same expansion : So the end product would be $(x^{11} - x^{16})$ .So both are fine and need 8 and 3. So would the answer be (8+5,8) - (3+5,3) ?

Comment: For $x^{19}$ you'll get the sum of 2 terms, $x^{11} \cdot 1 \cdot \binom{13}{8} x^8$ plus  $x^{11}\cdot  (-x^5) \cdot \binom{8}{3} x^3$, so yes $\binom{13}{8} - \binom{8}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most of the way home with what you have done already, the last step involves manipulating the summation  by multiplying through by $x^{11}(1-x^5)=x^{11}-x^{16}$ like so

$$\begin{align}(x^{11}-x^{16})\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5}x^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5}(x^{n+11}-x^{n+16})\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5}x^{n+11}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5}x^{n+16}\end{align}$$

relabelling summation indices $n\rightarrow n-11$ and $n\rightarrow n-16$ for the first and second summations respectively gives

$$\sum_{n=11}^{\infty}\binom{n-6}{5}x^{n}-\sum_{n=16}^{\infty}\binom{n-11}{5}x^{n}$$

but if we define $\binom{a}{b}=0$ for $a\lt b$ such that $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ then we can write this as

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n-6}{5}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n-11}{5}x^{n}$$

or simply

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\binom{n-6}{5}-\binom{n-11}{5}\right)x^n$$

hence your coefficients $c_n$ in

$$\frac{x^{11}-x^{16}}{(1-x)^6}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$$

are

$$c_n=\binom{n-6}{5}-\binom{n-11}{5}\tag{Answer}$$

e.g. To find the coefficient $x^{15}$ plug $n=15$ into that formula.

Comment: Thankyou Sir. This helped a lot :D

Comment: You are most welcome @Johnathan :)

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{15}]}&\color{blue}{x^{11}(1-x^5)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+5}{5}x^n}\\
> &=[x^4](1-x^5)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+5}{5}x^n\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^4]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+5}{5}x^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{9}{5}\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=126}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (2) we note the term $x^5$ does not contribute to the coefficient of $x^4$ and can be skipped.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^4$.

> In general we obtain for $k\geq 0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{k}]}&\color{blue}{x^{11}(1-x^5)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+5}{5}x^n}\\
> &=[x^{k-11}](1-x^5)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+5}{5}x^n\tag{4}\\
> &=\left([x^{k-11}]-[x^{k-16}]\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+5}{5}x^n\tag{5}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{k-6}{5}-\binom{k-11}{5}}\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we apply the same rule as in (1).
- In (5) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the same rule as in (1).
- In (6) we select the coefficients accordingly. Note that here we set $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k>n$ or $n<0$.